# How to reduce my iOS app's bundle size?

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks, ios-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS app that integrates with multiple bluetooth devices (e.g. printers and barcode scanners). Each of the devices comes with it's own version of SDK and most of them just have objective-c/swift SDKs but not javascript SDKs.

Would like to find out what is the best way to reduce the app bundle size at the same time supporting multiple devices ?

Based on my investigations,

iOS doesn't allow downloading objective-c/swift code dynamically during runtime, hence the option of downloading the SDKs after the user having installed the app is ruled out.

Would like to get a feedback on the feasibility of the below solution. Also let me know if there is a better solution.

> iOS version 8+ support embedded frameworks - Have separate iOS driver
>   apps for each of the supported devices which just installs the device
>   SDK as a shared embedded framework so that the parent app can
>   dynamically link to the shared embedded framework if one that matches
>   the connected device is available, otherwise force the user to
>   download the respective driver app.

Answer (score 0):

This question has gone unanswered for a little while, so you may have already figured this out, but **no**, you cannot make shared embedded frameworks on iOS. Only Apple can do that. All of the frameworks you use must be either provided by Apple or embedded inside your app.